# Shopware 6: How to update the messenger.yaml with Docker exec in Git Bash using sed command

Tags: docker, sed, git-bash, shopware6, docker-exec

I'm running a Bash script on Windows Git Bash that uses `docker exec` to update the `messenger.yaml` file in my Shopware container. I am encountering an issue with a `sed` command in my bash script, and I am seeking help to resolve it. I have the following `sed` command in my script:

```rb
FIND="# 'App\\Message\\YourMessage':"
REPLACE='Swag\\CodePlugin\\ScheduledTask\\SendCodePluginInvitationTask:'

docker exec $SHOPWARE_CONTAINER_ID sed -i "s/$FIND/$REPLACE/g" $FILE
```

when I run the script, I receive the following error:

```rb
sed: -e expression #1, char 36: unknown option to `s'
```

When I change this `"# 'App\\Message\\YourMessage':"` to `"'App\\Message\\YourMessage':"` it changes the content of the file. But I want to remove `#` as well.

Any help or suggestions on how to correct this sed command would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you change this in your image, or in an entrypoint wrapper script?  Anything you do with `docker exec` will be lost as soon as the container exits.  I've also seen a couple of questions that result from Git Bash rewriting paths, and a Dockerfile will use a more conventional shell.  It'd also be helpful to know what base image is in your Dockerfile; if `sed -i` requires a file extension argument you can get syntax errors like this.

Comment: As described in the question, when I use `"'App\\Message\\YourMessage':"` it works as expected. But I want to remove `#` as well. I want to have changes in the run time.

Comment: I am using latest image of Dockware/Play

Comment: A simpiler test case on the cmd line doesn't have a problem deleting `#` prefixed string, i.e. `echo "#xyz" | sed 's/#xyz/abc/'` produces `abc`. I have no experience w docker, but I guess I would try escaping the `#` char (possibly more than once) OR recompose your `$FIND` string so it is enclosed with single quotes, i.e. `FIND='# '"'"'App\\Message\\YourMessage'"'"':'` (untested). Good luck.

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and use Python or PHP instead for RegEx (basically anything but bash). Perhaps even better, just source the finished file by copying it over. Changes can persist, but you have to e.g. mount your www dir from your host. Nobody is forcing us to use Dockware. Also, RegEx replace is super hard in bash due to having to escape literals. Etc.